# Convert negative numbers to zero when averaging in Excel

Tags: excel

How do you convert negative numbers to 0 when writing an average function in Excel?

I have a column with a mix of positive and negative values and would like the negative values to be converted to +ve when I run the average function.

This is the context of what I am doing so far. Ideally, I would prefer a situation that does not involve VBA usage.

```
=AVERAGE(C:C)
```

Comment: Also, by converting to 0, do you mean to use a zero value in the average, or just ignore that value?

Comment: @Gaffi yeah and I mean to use the -ve number as a zero value in the average.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ignore the negative numbers, use

```
=AVERAGEIF(C:C,">0")
```

To use the zeros as part of the average, use:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,">0")/COUNT(C:C)
```

Where `C:C` is your range to get the average from (from your given example).

---

To echo grandocu's suggestion, to get the STDEV, you can use an array formula:

```
=STDEV.P(IF(C:C>0,C:C,0))
```

Depending on how many records you're focusing on, I would also possibly suggest creating a new column with values related to your original date. i.e. if you have a column `C:C` with positive and negative values, enter into column `D:D` a formula like so:

```
=IF(C2>0,C2,0)
```

Then, run your averages/stdev calculations on column D instead. This will help keep from having to use complicated/less common formulas, and visually may make things easier to understand when looking at your datasheet.

Comment: Thanks for the response! How would I do this for STDEV?

Comment: I don't think you want COUNTIF as part of the solution for averaging with negatives as zero - that will treat negatives as 1, try just `=SUMIF(C:C,">0")/COUNT(C:C)`

Answer (score 6):

You can just type in `=AVERAGE(IF(LEN(C:C)>0,ABS(C:C),""))` if you want to turn -ve into +ve then average them.  Remember you need to hit `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` when entering this cell so it performs it as an array formula.

To turn -ve into 0 then average it use this `=AVERAGE(IF(LEN(C:C)>0,IF(C:C<0,0,C:C),""))` and enter as an array formula as well (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

To respond to the above comment, you can just replace `AVERAGE` with `STDEV.P` to get standard deviation.  the other portion of the formula just checks the cell and ignores it if it's blank, turns it to 0 if it's negative, or just passes it if it's >=0.

Comment: `To turn -ve into 0 then average` + 1 for actually answering the question :)